# proguard removing chunktemplate functionality on release build

Tags: java, android, template-engine, chunk-templates

## Problem description

Chunk template(https://code.google.com/p/chunk-templates/) functionality works correct with my debug builds. 
If i make a release build with the same code, it just stops working. If i disable proguard in my release build everything is working again. So I'm sure its proguard removing too much from the library during optimization.

While i made my first release build, there were some error messages about chunk template code.
Using the following progurad statement was able to generate a release build (-dontwarn com.x5.**). After some testing, I've found out that the chunk template functionality was not working.

## Statements that I've tried (from proguard config)

- libraryjars /home/ydoganc/projects/contract_info/libs/chunk_2.4/chunk_template_2.4.jar
- dontwarn com.x5.** #does compile without error but not working
- keep class net.minidev.json.** {*;}
- keep class com.x5.template.** { *; }
- keep class net.minidev.** { *; }

Is there a way to prevent proguard handling the library jars? It looks like proguard is not 
doing what the config files tell its to do.

## Error messages of proguard(after disabling the -dontwarn com.x5.**... statement):

```
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.JSONValue
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.JSONValue
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.JSONArray
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.parser.ContainerFactory
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.parser.ContainerFactory
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.MacroTag: can't find referenced class net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Base64DecodeFilter: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Base64DecodeFilter: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Base64DecodeFilter: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Base64EncodeFilter: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Base64EncodeFilter: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Base64EncodeFilter: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.ParseException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.ParseException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.ParseException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.JEP
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.template.filters.Calc: can't find referenced class org.cheffo.jeplite.ParseException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.Introspector
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.Introspector
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.BeanInfo
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.BeanInfo
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.IntrospectionException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.BeanInfo
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.IntrospectionException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$MadRobotIntrospector: can't find referenced class com.madrobot.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: com.x5.util.ObjectDataMap$StandardIntrospector: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] Warning: there were 55 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-10-28 23:33:32 - ContractInfoListActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: You at least need ```keep class com.x5.util.** { *; }``` in addition to the other "keep" lines

Comment: I have tried tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. Only way for me to create a working apk is to disable proguard.

Comment: I put all my library jars directly in the libs/ folder (not in a subfolder) and the only thing in my proguard-project.txt file is ```-ignorewarnings``` I set up a sample project with just chunk and json-smart and the release apk is working fine.  Are you using the madrobot stuff at all?

Comment: After you build the release apk, what is the output of grep "^com.x5" bin/proguard/mapping.txt ? This would tell us for sure if any important classes are missing.  Please open an issue at https://github.com/tomj74/chunk-templates/issues and post the output there.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1069218 Were you able to find a solution ? I'm trying to make a build with proguard enabled (for this lib https://github.com/kexanie/MathView which also uses chunktemplate) but event after adding all the above "keep" lines, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @RmK any luck?  Please open an issue on github, I'd like to get to the bottom of this and then post an answer here for others.

Comment: @TomMcClure Yup. Solved it based on your comment. https://github.com/kexanie/MathView/issues/9
Though I must say, I can still see warning here n there related to this, in build build log, but they're not a blocker so far and the feature works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

Add this following into your proguard-project.txt file

```
-dontwarn com.x5.**
-keep class com.x5.template.** { *; }
-keep class com.x5.util.** { *; }
```

Hope this helps.